# expdp full export not exporting all schemas

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, datapump

On Oracle 12c, fairly new database with APEX installed. I do a

```
 expdp \"/ as sysdba\"  directory=dp_dir full=y dumpfile=full.dmp logfile=full.log
```

And I am getting just a few tables from SYS and SYSTEM exported:

```
. . exported "SYS"."KU$_USER_MAPPING_VIEW"               5.882 KB      24 rows
. . exported "SYS"."AUD$"                                    0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "SYS"."DAM_CLEANUP_EVENTS$"                     0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "SYS"."DAM_CLEANUP_JOBS$"                       0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "SYS"."DAM_CONFIG_PARAM$"                   6.523 KB      14 rows
. . exported "SYS"."TSDP_ASSOCIATION$"                       0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "SYS"."TSDP_CONDITION$"                         0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "SYS"."TSDP_FEATURE_POLICY$"                    0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "SYS"."TSDP_PARAMETER$"                     5.945 KB       1 rows
. . exported "SYS"."TSDP_POLICY$"                        5.914 KB       1 rows
. . exported "SYS"."TSDP_PROTECTION$"                        0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "SYS"."TSDP_SENSITIVE_DATA$"                    0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "SYS"."TSDP_SENSITIVE_TYPE$"                    0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "SYS"."TSDP_SOURCE$"                            0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "SYS"."TSDP_SUBPOL$"                        6.320 KB       1 rows
. . exported "SYSTEM"."REDO_DB"                          25.58 KB       1 rows
. . exported "SYSTEM"."REDO_LOG"                             0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "SYS"."FGA_LOG$FOR_EXPORT"                      0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "SYSTEM"."SCHEDULER_JOB_ARGS"               8.671 KB       4 rows
. . exported "SYSTEM"."SCHEDULER_PROGRAM_ARGS"           10.21 KB      22 rows
. . exported "SYS"."AUDTAB$TBS$FOR_EXPORT"               5.953 KB       2 rows
. . exported "SYS"."DBA_SENSITIVE_DATA"                      0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "SYS"."DBA_TSDP_POLICY_PROTECTION"              0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "SYS"."NACL$_ACE_EXP"                       10.14 KB       3 rows
. . exported "SYS"."NACL$_HOST_EXP"                      6.976 KB       2 rows
. . exported "SYS"."NACL$_WALLET_EXP"                        0 KB       0 rows
Master table "SYS"."SYS_EXPORT_FULL_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
```

Yet I know I have tables and other objects in other schemas:

```
AtlasProd:SYS@extern01> select owner, 
  2  decode(segment_type, 'TABLE', 'TABLE', '-other-') as segment_type,
  3  count(*)
  4  from dba_segments
  5  group by owner, decode(segment_type, 'TABLE', 'TABLE', '-other-')
  6  order by 1, 2;

OWNER                          SEGMENT_TYPE         COUNT(*)
------------------------------ ------------------ ----------
APEX_050000                    -other-                   646
APEX_050000                    TABLE                     155
AUDSYS                         -other-                     6
DBSNMP                         -other-                     4
DBSNMP                         TABLE                       2
GSMADMIN_INTERNAL              -other-                    15
GSMADMIN_INTERNAL              TABLE                       6
OUTLN                          -other-                     6
OUTLN                          TABLE                       3
SYS                            -other-                  1987
SYS                            TABLE                    1059
SYSTEM                         -other-                   321
SYSTEM                         TABLE                     124
XDB                            -other-                   655
XDB                            TABLE                      49

15 rows selected.
```

I see a workaround at [Export pump all schemas except Sytem related schemas](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114443/export-pump-all-schemas-except-sytem-related-schemas) but I know I've used `full=y` before successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behaviour.

[FULL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-BA07401C-6261-4B07-AD2C-06CD0A6E0BE9.htm#SUTIL851)

> A full export does not, by default, export system schemas that contain
>   Oracle-managed data and metadata. Examples of system schemas that are
>   not exported by default include SYS, ORDSYS, and MDSYS.

[12.1.0.1 EXPDP Does Not Export APEX Schema (Doc ID 1912162.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=1912162.1)

> This is the expected behavior in 12.1.0.X version,
>
> This was added, in part, to avoid problem with common objects in a 
>   multi-tenant DB, but certainly has been very helpful in eliminating
>   errors  report - particularly in full import.  The bit is called
>   'ORACLE_MAINTAINED' in [user,all,dba]_objects  dictionary views. Seems
>   pretty reasonable that Oracle maintained objects are  not be moved
>   around by datapump.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the system user for full datapump export/import operations.  Using "/ as sysdba" or "sys as sysdba" may give you unpredictable results.

> Do not start Export as SYSDBA, except at the request of Oracle
>   technical support. SYSDBA is used internally and has specialized
>   functions; its behavior is not the same as for general users.

Source: [Oracle 12c Datapump Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-D5455260-C28C-475F-9E0E-2BE227E7F0E3.htm#SUTIL824)

Comment: This is true, but does not answer the question. And I doubt that by using `system`, the built-in schemas such as `XDB` would be exported, as my own tests proved otherwise.

Comment: Correct, I thought `SYSTEM` would get the APEX_05000 schemas but it didn't; as you noted in your answer.  I marked this answer as correct a little too soon :)